# Git compare with upstream committerdate to the second

Tags: git

I often rebase the same branch from different machines, so its not immediately clear if the branch I'm working on has the latest change and I just haven't pushed, or if that latest change was made somewhere else and I just haven't pulled.

I have a git alias to show all the local branches with upstreams and committerdates.

`branc = "!f() { git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/heads/$@ --format='%(color:red)%(objectname:short=8)%(color:reset) %(color:yellow)%(refname:short)%(color:reset) %(color:cyan)%(upstream:strip=2)%(color:reset) %(color:green)%(upstream:track)%(color:reset) (%(color:yellow)%(committerdate:iso-strict)%(color:reset)/%(color:cyan)%(committerdate:iso-strict)%(color:reset))'; }; f"`

produces lines like

`cc15e795 10496-standardise-common origin/10496-standardise-common  (2022-01-26T14:07:21+02:00/2022-01-26T14:07:21+02:00)`

Q1: As you can see it's not using the upstream committerdate 
Q2: iso-strict is the most compact to-the-sec date format, but is there a way to ditch the timezone?

Answer (score 1):

*About the upstream's committer date:*

I don't know how to do that using only `for-each-ref` formatting tags.

You could alwats use `for-each-ref` to print your ref names, and pipe this through a script which can get the upstream's committer date and print it (be wary of your color codes, though).

You may also use the [`--shell`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---shell) option to have `git for-each-ref` generate a shell script for you (or a perl or python script), which you can then `eval` or execute.

*About the formatting:*

There is a syntax to format your timestamp using `strftime` (see link to docs below), so you can choose whatever format you see fit.

Try one of the following :

```
# this one should use the timezone stored with each git timestamp :
--format="%(committerdate:format:%FT%T)"   # %F: full date (Y-M-D) %T: full time (H:M:S)

# this one should convert all timestamps to your env timezone before formatting :
--format="%(committerdate:format-local:%FT%T)"

# to say "show me all timestamps in UTC", you can set the 'TZ' env variable :
TZ=UTC git for-each-ref --format="%(committerdate:format-local:%FT%T)"
```

Check `man strftime` for all possible format strings (`%Y, %m (<- month), %d, %H, %M (<- minutes), %S` etc ...).

---

The doc for [`git help for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-contentslinesN) says (a few paragraphs below the link) :

> As a special case for the date-type fields, you may specify a format for the date by adding :
> followed by date format name (see the values the --date option to git-rev-list(1) takes)

In [`git help rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---dateltformatgt) (or [`git help log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---dateltformatgt)), you will see :

> `--date=<format>`
>
> [...]
>
> `--date=format:...`  feeds the format `...`  to your system `strftime`, except for %s, %z, and %Z, which are handled internally.

and read the details there.

Comment: thank you, format solved. Q1 is unresolved: its not displaying the committerdate of the upstream head commit

Comment: @caduceus: yes, I initially misread your question. Perhaps you could reword that part : "is there a way to get the committer date of the *upstream* commit ?", AFAIK there isn't

Comment: hmmm, I had forgotten there is a [`--shell`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---shell) option to generate a shell script, which you can then `eval` or execute. See the [3rd example](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_examples) further down.